# Can we change the spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors after creating a spark session?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Apache Spark and I was reading about setting different configurations for the spark session.My question is what if we set executor memory while building a spark session can we change it after creating the session in case we want more memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you restart Sparkconext. I have never done that to date.

YARN dynamic resource allocation can change certain things, but that is out of your explicit control.

Comment: I read somewhere that there are certain properties that can be only configured after creating a spark session and there are some that can be configured before also.

Comment: That would be new to me. There ate defaults and overriding via conf.